# XML Schema - Element with maxOccurs="unbounded" containing multiple acceptable types

Tags: xml, xsd, uml

is it possible to make XSD schema for an element with maxOccurs="unbounded" which accepts different value types as its items? for example:

```
<myArray>
    <A>first</A>
    <A>second</A>
    <A>third</A>
    <B>fourth</B>
    <B>fifth</B>
</myArray>
```

if not, is it a non-standard type of designing XML structures?

similarly in XHTML:

```
<body>
    <p></p>
    <br />
    <img />
</body>
```

is this mean that xhtml is not standard?

**Updated:** maxOccurs="unbounded" previously was called "Array Element"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, i found the way by using xsd refs.
**Conclusion: It is possible and XHTML is standard.**

schema for "myArray":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="A" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="myArray">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="A" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="B" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

XSD does not identify any class of elements as "array elements", so it's not entirely clear what you mean by your question.  There is no requirement in XSD that all children of an element have the same name, or the same type.

XSD does require, by means of the "Element Declarations Consistent" constraint, that any two siblings with the same name have the same type (or compatible types, with 'compatibility' defined by some rather dense and complicated prose).

Since heterogeneous arrays cause difficulties in some programming languages, I can imagine some programmers wanting to design their XML to avoid constructs which would map into heterogeneous arrays.  But the design of XHTML is in no sense non-standard.

Comment: by the "array elements" i was pointing to an element with maxOccur="unbound". i also updated the question with true words.

Comment: so how's the schema for my example? do you mean that's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Better use the following xsd-solution. Because with this it'S also possible to mix the order of your element  and .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="myArray">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:group ref="ElementGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>   
  
  <xs:group name="ElementGroup">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="A" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:group>
  
</xs:schema>
```

Following xml is then also possible:

```
<myArray>
    <A>first</A>
    <A>second</A>
    <A>third</A>
    <B>fourth</B>
    <B>fifth</B>
    <A>sixth</A>
    <B>seventh</B>
</myArray>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).